# Comparing description of spontaneous absorption and description of stimulated emission

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser, electronic-band-theory, photon-emission

I am currently studying *Diode Lasers and Photonic Integrated Circuits*, Second Edition, by Larry A. Coldren, Scott W. Corzine, Milan L. Masanovic. Chapter **1.3 SPONTANEOUS AND STIMULATED TRANSITIONS: THE CREATION OF LIGHT** says the following:

> [image]
>
> The second illustration ($R_{12}$) outlines photon absorption, which stimulates the generation of an electron in the conduction band while leaving a hole in the valence band.
> The third process ($R_{21}$) is exactly the same as the second, only the sign of the interaction is reversed. Here an incident photon perturbs the system, stimulating the recombination of an electron and hole and simultaneously generating a new photon. Of course, this is the all-important positive gain mechanism that is necessary for lasers to operate.

$R_{12}$ makes sense, since it's referred to as photon *absorption*, and, as we can see, the photon is indeed *absorbed* in transitioning the electron in the valence band to the conduction band. As figure 1.6 shows, there is no emission of a photon here as a result of this transition.

The authors then state that $R_{21}$ is "exactly the same" as $R_{12}$, only that "the sign of the interaction is reversed." But if we use figure 1.6 to compare $R_{21}$ with $R_{12}$, we can see that this is **not** the case: $R_{21}$ involves absorbing a photon, which transitions the electron in the conduction band to the valence band, but, unlike $R_{12}$, where there is no resulting emission of a photon, there is the emission of *two* photons! So what's going on here? Is the description provided by the authors incorrect? Is figure 1.6 incorrect? Or, perhaps, am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: No, the incoming photon stimulates the release of the second photon. But it is true that the release of the second photon is the time-reversal of the absorption event.

Comment: No photon is absorbed in stimulated emission and only one new photon is created.

Comment: Huh? It sounds like you're both saying contradictory things. @ProfRob If the photon is absorbed, then why is there two being emitted after the absorption of the incoming photon and the transition of the electron from the conduction band to the valence band?

Comment: No photon is absorbed in stimulated emission.

Comment: @ProfRob Oh. When the authors said that it is "exactly the same", only that "the sign of the interaction is reversed," I assumed that included the absorption of the photon.

Comment: At the first sight, it seems 'strange' to call absorption, a stimulated absorption. But when I looked back at the book (Laser fundamentals by Silvast), I found the following explanation: absorption could also have been referred to as 'stimulated' absorption, since it requires electromagnetic energy to stimulate the electron and thereby produce the excitation.

Comment: The meaning of 'exactly the same' is maybe related to the thermodynamic equilibrium or microscopic reversibility: if a photon can stimulate an electron to move from a lower energy state to higher energy state (i.e. absorption), then a photon should also be able to stimulate and electron from the same upper to lower state.